# ionic app not allowed to access photo data

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

i am using this code to save image from dataUrl, it is giving error permission denied. How to save image with this dataUrl in app folder?

```
this.PhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization().then(() => {
   this.PhotoLibrary.saveImage(dataUrl,'MyHomeLibrary',options).then((data) => {
     console.log('data',data);

  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
    // Do stuff after you have permission!
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by doing this

```
this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization({read:true,write:true})
```

Found the answer here - [Android oreo : Permission Denial: This application is not allowed to access Photo data.](https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library/issues/113)

UPDATE:

> From Android O we have to call request Authorization method like below
>
> this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization()
>
> The Above method need to replace with
>
> this.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization({read:true,write:true})

Comment: Great answer. Can you post the relevant information from that link in your answer in case that link goes down.